# How to find the list of all journals to scrape like google scholar?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, google-scholar

I want to find the list of all isi articles and journals like google scholar.

I think we have some websites like https://www.thomsonreuters.com/en.html that's contain the link of all journals, can I use this kind of websites to find the link of all journals?

Do you have any better idea please?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a website that you say has all the links you want to find all the links you want? If so, the answer is probably yes. You might want to rephrase your question. Have you tried anything yet? Run into any issue?

Comment: Dear @Gallaecio, I can crawl and scrap most of websites, but I need to make sure which method is better to find the most of journals to scrap. Actually I need a list of websites contain most journal links in different science and also if you have any better idea please share to me.